# couldn't connect to ftp in android but connects in java

Tags: java, android, ftp

I got complete code from this [blog post](http://zanailhan.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-connect-to-ftp-server-example.html). I am able to get this working with javac(windows java compiler) but in android studio it says couldn't connect to the server. Jar files has been placed rightly in libs folder, compile files('libs/jar') function has been added in built.grade

All, I did extra is created FTP object and called methods provided on the blog post and fixed the this code in `OnCreate()`:

```
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username,
                      String password, int port)
```

I have also added Internet permission my internet is also on. No errors are showing exception the exception. `"Error: could not connect to host " + host`

```
public class Ftp {

public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;

                        // Connect to the FTP server
public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password, int port){
    try{
        mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
        // connecting to the host

        Log.d("before","got entered");
        mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
        Log.d("after connect()", "didn't got connected");
        // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
        if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())){
            //login using username & password
            Log.d("Final_Message", "Didn't got positive reply for connection");
            boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);

            /*Set File Transfer
            To avoid corruption issue you must specified a correct transfer mode,
            such as ASCII_FILE_TYPE, BINARY_FILE_TYPE, etc. Here, I use Binary file type
            for transferring text, image, and compressed files.
             */
            mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            return status;
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERRO", "Error: could not connect to host" + host);
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean ftpUpload(/*String srcFilePath, String desFileName, String desDirectory*/){
    boolean status = false;
    try{
        FileInputStream srcFileStream = new FileInputStream("abhimanyu.txt"/*srcFilePath*/);
        status = mFTPClient.storeFile("abhimanyu", srcFileStream);
        // change working directory to the destrination directory
        /*if(ftpChangeDirectory(desDirectory)){
            status = mFTPClient.storeFile(desFileName, srcFileStream);
        }*/
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERRO", "upload filed");
    }

    return status;
}


}
```

***Gradle files:***

**build.gradle(Project:FTPConnection)**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
 }
```

**built.gradle(Module:app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-    android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/commons-net-3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
}
```

There are too many logs for my android device so I am pasting the selected logs for my code which shows error in connection.

**LOGS**

```
08-27 16:09:49.840  28535-28535/? D/before﹕ got entered
08-27 16:09:49.840  28535-28535/? D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: hostname=xxxxx; servname=(null); cache_mode=(null), netid=0; mark=0
08-27 16:09:49.840  28535-28535/? D/libc-netbsd﹕ [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=xxxxx; ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
08-27 16:09:49.840  28535-28535/? D/ERRO﹕ Error: could not connect to hostcp.mdurtk.in
08-27 16:09:49.840  28535-28535/? D/ERRO﹕ upload filed
08-27 16:09:49.840  28535-28535/? I/Activity﹕ Activity.onPostResume() called
08-27 16:09:49.850  28535-28556/? D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
08-27 16:09:49.850  28535-28535/? D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
08-27 16:09:49.860    1246-4970/? D/SplitWindow﹕ check instance of lgWin Window{1395dc05 u0 com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection/com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection.MainActivity}
08-27 16:09:49.860    1246-4970/? V/WindowManager﹕ Adding window Window{1395dc05 u0 com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection/com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection.MainActivity} at 4 of 14 (before Window{23ed7caa u0 Starting com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection})
08-27 16:09:49.880  28535-28556/? I/Adreno﹕ QUALCOMM build                   : 76ae100, Ie081474390
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Ftp obj = new Ftp();
    obj.ftpConnect("******", "*****", "*****", 21);
    obj.ftpUpload();

    TextView f = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
    f.setText("Uploaded to server");
}
```

**Exception Logs**

```
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? D/ERRO﹕ Exception log starts here
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:426)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:255)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:308)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:192)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection.Ftp.ftpConnect(Ftp.java:23)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5424)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? D/ERRO﹕ Error: could not connect to hostcp.mdurtk.in
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? D/ERRO﹕ upload failed
08-27 16:50:44.953    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: abhimanyu.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection.Ftp.ftpUpload(Ftp.java:177)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.muchmore.www.ftpconnection.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:162)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5424)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:913)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:706)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
08-27 16:50:44.963    8963-8963/? W/System.err﹕ ... 17 more
```

Comment: We need to see the exception that was caught in the `catch(Exception e)` in the code. The exception that's thrown as a result of that (`"Error: could not connect to host " + host`) is useless for any debugging.

Comment: Also do you run the Android studio on the same machine as javac?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have edited my question. Is this information enough or You want more logs? You might wanna remove downvote now :)

Comment: I have hided those credentials with stars. Hope you understand.

Comment: What about the exception?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl You see in catch block i haven't written e.printStackTrace() but the Log messages....do you want me to write printStackTrace() message in exception blocks

Comment: Yes please. Full exception details.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl added exception logs